# Jeasyui DataGrid Pagination is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a datagrid which fetches data from DB as "rows" and "total" and assigned to easy-ui Datagrid by url which works fine. But, adding Pagination using data-option="pagination:true" adds pagination toolbar but it list all entries by default it should show only 10 records whereas it listing all the records.

What will be the fix for this??

Action
            Name
            Privilege

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this:

`$('#dgMyTreeGrid').treegrid({`
    `pagination:true,`
    `pageSize:10,` (or 20 etc. multiples of 10)
    `...`